# Make image occupy the entire viewport

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, viewport

I have this dev [website](https://i-am-gia-dev.myshopify.com/products/pixie-jacket-red#&gid=1&pid=1). If you click on an image, it will pop-up a photo slider (using photoswipe). Is there a way to **make the image
occupy the entire viewport**? I have tried `height: 100vh, width: auto`, but with no luck

[image]

Comment: Unable to view your website the link it's redirecting to login screen.

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui, ok sorry about that. Let me think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could always apply:

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

To the container, it'll get it done, but it's pretty severe in terms of properly structuring stuff.